# Simultaneous equation, is my reasoning correct here?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Determine the value of $k$ such that the matrix is the augmented matrix of a linear system with infinitely many solutions.
>
> $$\left(\begin{array}{cc|r}
> 8 & -4 &  5\\ 
> 16 & k &  10\\ 
>
> \end{array}\right)$$

Well if I divide row 2 by 2, I get
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc|r}
8 & -4 &  5\\ 
8 & k/2 &  5\\ 
\end{array}\right)$$

So when $k = -8$ both of these equations are the same and the bottom row will be all zeroes if I use the row operation Row 2 minus Row 1.

That means I will be left with $8x - 4y = 5$ which has infinitely many solutions. So the answer is $k = -8$. Is that correct? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: See [this meta discussion](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3589) for a suggestion about how to ask these questions - you might consider posting your own argument as an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, your reasoning is exactly right! Though  ideally, you should explain why $k=-8$ is the **only** value of $k$ for which there are infinitely many solutions, since the problem says "the".